# file_put_contents Permission denied when trying to write to /tmp/filename in MAMP

Tags: php, permissions, mamp

I was trying to write to a file in the `/tmp` directory on MAC from a php file running on a MAMP server. It keeps on Permission denied. Is it because MAMP is executed on a local environment and how can I fix it.
The error it gives is

```
file_put_contents(/tmp/frenzyarticle.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```